# Iterating over pandas Series only executes once

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, for-loop

I have more than 8000 items in the "index", but the for loop only does the job for the first item.

```
from datetime import datetime
from pandas import Series
from pandas import DataFrame

series = Series.from_csv('something.csv', header=1)
index = DataFrame(series.index)

for item in index:
    dt = datetime.strptime(item, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
    dt = dt.time().isoformat()
    print(dt)
```

So the items in index column look like this: `1998-02-14 19:30:54.052000`

And the for loop does this `19:30:54.052000`, but only for the first line. Any idea why?

Comment: It would be beneficial if you included a sample of `index` which reproduces this behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not how you loop over a series's items. What you did iterates over the *columns*, and in a series, there's only one. That's why it executes only once. Use [`Series.iteritems`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iteritems.html) if there's no way to achieve your goal by vectorized operations.

```
for idx, item in index.iteritems():
    dt = ...
```

But in this case, you can use [`Series.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) instead of a for-loop.

```
index.apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f").time().isoformat())
```

Comment: Thank you! it works. Now I get another error, from "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f". The thing is I have some data with decimal seconds and some without (for example:  19:30:54.052000 and simply 19:30:55). How can I make it work for both types? Thank you again!

Comment: That's a different question, and you should post it as such. If you need to, you can refer to this question by including a link.

Comment: Thank you, I fixed it meanwhile.